# Facebook "Unsupported post request" Android SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am posting on facebook fanpage using graph api with Android SDK.

I have used page access token for post.

I have used below key in bundle for post request while posting

```
picture
access_token
link
name
```

I am getting error like this in response and post on page also successfully done with link.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported post request.}, isFromCache:false}
```

when i remove link key from request, its working fine and give response.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"id":"1462005247419467_1473063782980280"}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

which is wrong in my request or any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/726825557390253/

issue in facebook sdk that's why this error comes.

now issue fix with new sdk 3.18.

if anyone facing this issue,update new sdk 3.18 or latest.